# New groovy install roscore error

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did a full-desktop install on a netbook and workstation Ubuntu 12.04 that had a working Fuerte (/opt/ros/fuerte/ folder still there) & modified the .bashrc to only source groovy:

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.2.18
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.2.32:11311   
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

roscore gives following error:

```
$~/ros_workspace$ roscore
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Cannot locate [roslaunch]Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1].
```

Param xml is

Environment paths only point to groovy folders. Should I delete or move the /opt/ros/fuerte/ folder?

What should I check?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61995/new-groovy-install-roscore-error/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-05-02**:
I suspect this is related to http://answers.ros.org/question/61981/is-rosversion-broken-on-groovy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ahendrix advice led to discovering that several packages were indeed installed by pip, which somewhere in the process I removed. So installed pip from Aptitude. Also with another ROS Answer from hersh 'cannot run roscore due to error in rosversion', Oct 19 '12  uninstalled rosinstall, rospkg, rosdep, vcstools, catkin-pkg, pyYusb with "sudo pip uninstall PACKAGE", several times in some cases until that package was not found. However, now still have one error message from roscore,

~$ roscore

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/bin/roscore", line 62, in  import roslaunch

File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/**init**.py", line 46, in  import rospkg

ImportError: No module named rospkg

Fixed by installing python-rospkg with aptitude ($sudo apt-get install python-rospkg) and apt-get update that did a lot of cleanup.

---

Originally posted by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) with karma: 141 on 2013-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1